# Parametrizing find from properties file

Tags: regex, bash

In a certain script, let's call it search.sh I have:

search.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
. $CONFIG/common/common.properties
FILES_TO_CHECK=$(find $DIRECTORY -type f -regex $PATTERN)
```

In the file common properties I have something like this:

```
DIRECTORY="$ENVS/$ENVD/{DIR1,DIR2}/"
```

Whenever I execute the script I receive:

```
find: /home/env/dom/{DIR1,DIR2}: No such file or directory
```

but If I use it like this:

```
find $ENVS/$ENVD/{DIR1,DIR2}/ -type f -regex $PATTERN
```

It works like a charm. I tried to use '', "" in properties around that path, but without success. Could anyone tell me how to solve the problem to have this path in my properties so find will use it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like you are assigning variable  `$DIRECTORY` incorrectly. Try to do the same but without `$` inside your common.properties file

As far as start code was changed - here is an answer on updated version.

The problem is that **brace expansion**: `{}` should be evaluated before the execution of find command. To do this you need explicitly call `eval` on your code. Try this:

> eval find $DIRECTORY

This should work.

Note: **brace expansion** might not work properly for other shells than bash 3+

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$` from `$DIRECTORY="$ENVS/$ENVD/{DIR1,DIR2}/"`

You have to assign the value to DIRECTORY and not execute it.